# Copy nodes with changed element values XSLT

Tags: xslt, copy

I have input xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1981</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

How do the follow?
For each "catalog/cd" 
1) if "year" = '1985', then copy all elemets of "catalog/cd" without changed values
2) else copy all elements "catalog/cd" without changed values, exclude elements "company" (need to set value 'MyCompany') and "country" (need to set value 'MyCountry')

Result XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>MyCountry</country>
    <company>MyCompany</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1981</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>MyCountry</country>
    <company>MyCompany</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different options to achieve what you need. You need to start with an `identity template` that would copy the input XML as is to output.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Next you can declare separate templates for modifying `country` and `company` where the `year != 1985`.

```
<xsl:template match="cd[year != '1985']/country">
    <country>MyCountry</country>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="cd[year != '1985']/company">
    <company>MyCompany</company>
</xsl:template>
```

Another option is to change the values of both elements in a single template `cd` whose child element `year != 1985`.

```
<xsl:template match="cd[year != '1985']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title | artist" />
        <country>MyCountry</country>
        <company>MyCompany</company>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="price | year" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Hope this helps. However you need to go online and do some reading / hands on tutorials related to XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <xsl:template match="catalog">
        <catalog>
        <xsl:for-each select="cd">
            <cd>
            <title>
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </title>
            <artist>
                <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
            </artist>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(year = 1985)">
                    <country>MY Country</country>
                    <company>My Company</company>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <country><xsl:value-of select="country"/></country>
                    <company><xsl:value-of select="company"/></company>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <price><xsl:value-of select="price"/></price>
            <year><xsl:value-of select="year"/></year>
            </cd>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </catalog>
    </xsl:template>
Check it, I may be helful for you
```